# Is there a simpler way to subtract quarter(3 months) from string in Python?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm trying to subtract a quarter from a string the input is formatted like that '2002q2' which means year = 2002 quarter 2.

I tried to define a function to do the job and it worked

```py
def subtract_quarter(s):
    y,q = map(int,tuple(s.split('q')))
    if q>1:
        q = q-1
    else:
        q=4
        y=y-1
    return 'q'.join([str(y),str(q)])
subtract_quarter('2000q1')
```

output:
'1999q4'

but is there an easier way or pythonic way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

We can definitely make this more compact and work with aribtrary deltas:

```
def add_quarters(s, dq):
    y,q = map(int, s.split('q'))
    yq2 = 4*y + q + dq
    return '{}q{}'.format(yq2//4, yq2%4)
```

For example:

```
>>> add_quarters('2000q4', 1)
'2001q1'
>>> add_quarters('2000q4', 15)
'2004q3'
>>> add_quarters('2000q4', -1)
'2000q3'
>>> add_quarters('2000q4', -5)
'1999q3'
```

We here can thus add/subtract an arbitrary number of quarters. By using `-1` we subtract a single quarter.

That being said, I'm not sure that using a string in the first place is a good idea. It might be better to just use an integer that represents the number of quarters (for example since January 1, 2000), or a `date` object. By using a string, you make it more prone to errors, since the string can contain `'foo-bar'` for example. By using an integer, at least the "format" of the value can not be incorrect.